# Better Reindent Lines Feature for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have found Sublime Text's Reindent Lines feature to not being very reliable or helpful, especially when dealing with JSON files. Does anyone know of a way to make it work better? I know of plugins like "HTML-CSS-JS Prettify" but they only (and quite correctly, I might add) strive to work with HTML, CSS and JS respectively. I'd love to know if there is better way to indent/reindent all kinds of files.

Bonus points for any hint regarding converting from tabs to spaces (or vice versa) and reindenting correctly in one go.

Answer (score 3):

[pretty JSON](https://github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson) package works perfectly for me.

You can specify the style of indentation from the package setting also. (which solves your second problem)

Comment: Nice! And what do you know: I already had it installed but never used it. Still, what about other languages like PHP, Python or JavaScript? Is ST designed in such a fashion that I'm supposed to hunt down and install all kinds of specialized plugins for the languages I use?

Comment: ST's reindent tool is not meant for correctly all kinds of messy code. Having a good coding style is much more important :) Anyways, I agree that Sublime's indentation sucks, (only considering curly braces, not counting the opening braces before any comments... ) but it forces us to write better code, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed. I strive very much for clean code but time and time again I need to clean up some other developers' spaghetti-code (and of course sometimes my own, older code). I know all devs experience and dread that. Erratic line breaks, mixed tabs and spaces, indentation varying between 2, 3, 4 and 8 spaces, whatever you can imagine, it's there. ;)